System.Text.Json deserialize class that implements IReadOnlyCollection
I have a class that implements IReadOnlyCollection<T> and I cannot deserialize json string produced during the serialization:
public class MyItems : IReadOnlyCollection<int>
{
    private readonly List<int> _items;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyItems(IReadOnlyCollection<int> items)
    {
        _items = items != null ? new List<int>(items) : new List<int>();
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Count => _items.Count;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

and the executing code:
MyItems myItems1 = new MyItems([1, 2, 3]);
string jsonStr = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(myItems1); // produces string '[1,2,3]'
MyItems? myItems2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyItems>(jsonStr); // throws

the exception thrown is:

System.NotSupportedException: 'The collection type 'MyItems' is abstract, an interface, or is read only, and could not be instantiated and populated. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.'

I would expect that ctor marked with [JsonConstructor] will be used, but possibly the issue is name of the argument..?
Is using of the custom JsonConverter the only way to go?
Oh.. almost forgot - using net9
Thanks in advance

Similar issue discussed in here: System.Text.Json Deserialization throws NotSupportedException when implementing IEnumerable<T> #46920
You have to implement the custom JSON converter for deserializing the IReadOnlyCollection<int> to the MyItems (POCO).
public class MyItemsConverter : JsonConverter<MyItems>
{
    public override MyItems Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        var obj = new MyItems(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IReadOnlyCollection<int>>(ref reader, options));

        return obj;
     }

     public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyItems value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
     {
         JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
     }
}

JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions {  };
options.Converters.Add(new MyItemsConverter());
        
MyItems? myItems2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyItems>(jsonStr, options);

Demo @ .NET Fiddle
